# Wiremock randomValues return as string and not number

Tags: wiremock

I'm using the [randomValues](https://wiremock.org/studio/docs/response-templating/random-values/) to return random numbers in my route response.

When I just return it, the value is returned as number. But if I send as a property in the response body, the value is returned as string. Can I return this as a numeric value?

My docker:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wiremock:
    image: wiremock/wiremock
    container_name: wiremock_server
    volumes:
      - ./wiremock:/home/wiremock
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
    command:
      - -verbose
      - -global-response-templating
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.30.0.0/16
```

My Wiremock mapping:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "/account/([0-9]*)/balance",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "{ \"balance\": \"{{randomValue length=9 type='NUMERIC'}}\" }"
  }
}
```

Response received:

```
{
    "balance": "499336545"
}
```

Response expectec:

```
{
    "balance": 499336545
}
```

I tried return only the randomValue and works, but I need this inside a body property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quoting the value in your response definition. Just use this:

```json
{
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "/account/([0-9]*)/balance",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "{ \"balance\": {{randomValue length=9 type='NUMERIC'}} }"
  }
}
```

Comment: Omg, it was right here under my nose hahahahah
but I made something wrong before, because I had sure that I tried without quotes...
thanks!!!